# Django Delete file from storage model not working from IIS but working on localhost

Tags: python, django, iis

I have file Delete Model for deleting file chosen by user. for that after conforming from user that you want to sure delete file I have view.py code as below.

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')

def Delete_files(request, pk):
# Get the RadioFile object based on the primary key (pk)
radio_file = get_object_or_404(RadioFile, pk=pk)
print(radio_file)
# get the file path and file object from the database
file_obj = RadioFile.objects.get(id=pk).audio_file    
radio = radio_file.audio_file
file_path =file_obj.path    
print(file_path)    

# Check that the user is the owner of the file    
if request.user != radio_file.uploaded_by:          
    messages.success(request, 'File can be deleted by its owner.') # store the message in a message queue
    return redirect('/')
elif os.path.exists(file_path) and not os.path.isfile(file_path):
    print(f"Error: {file_path} is not a file")
    response_data = {'success': False, 'error': str(e)}     
else:
    try :
        with transaction.atomic():
            # Remove the many-to-many relationship with categories
            radio_file.categories.clear()
            radio_file.share_with.clear()

            # Delete the Radio object
            radio_file.delete()

            # Delete the file from the filesystem
            radio.close()
            radio.delete()
            
            messages.success(request, 'Radio and file deleted successfully.')
            response_data = {'success': True}
    except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            messages.error(request, 'some error is coming while deleteing file.')
    # Redirect to the file list view        
    return redirect('/')
```

code deleting file when running from localhost. But it is giving me Win32 permission error says file already in use by other program. but file is open with python to list all files to user, when running from IIS server.

Please help.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, please post the full error message, you can also check whether there are related errors in the Event Viewer.

Comment: my error is [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:

Comment: You need more information to analyze the problem, please check if there are more error messages in consloe or Event Viewer.